# Open Source Naïve Bayes Classifier written in Java

Tags: java, open-source, bayesian, classification, bayesian-networks

I'm looking for an Open Source Naïve Bayes Classifier library written in Java. Would appreciate any help in finding one.

Is Naïve Bayes Classifier the same as Bayesian Network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout [Weka's implementations](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/classifiers/bayes/package-summary.html)

Comment: Note to readers not familiar with Weka: Weka has a GPL license (viral open source license).

Answer (score 7):

[Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) is in active development and has Bayesian classifier.

Answer (score 1):

Naïve Bayes classifiers are the simpler cousins of Bayesian belief networks: Both apply Bayes' theorem, but whereas Naïve Bayes performs a straightforward input-output mapping, belief networks can represent more complex relationships.